# Are folders under /usr/local/Caskroom needed after installation? (I'm wanting to delete them)

Tags: homebrew

Running macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). I am looking for folders which I can delete to free up some storage space. I see `/usr/local/Caskroom` seems to contain installation files for some packages which, I guess, I must have installed via `brew cask` or something.

Are the files under `/usr/local/Caskroom` needed for some purpose after installation? If not, then I could delete them without interfering with the installed packages, yes?

Answer (score 3):

The content of `Caskroom` **is** the installation, so removing a directory basically removes the installed cask.

```
$ ll /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver
lrwxr-xr-x  1 verence  wheel  62 Apr  1 16:49 /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver@ -> /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/chromedriver/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver
```

PS: "Normal" formulae are installed into `$(brew --prefix)/Cellar`, Casks into `$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom`. In both cases, symlinks from `bin` etc. ensure that files show up in the right places.

Comment: Hmm, on my system it appears that /usr/local/Caskroom/foo/version/Foo.app just points to /Applications/Foo.app, so the installation files are somewhere else ... However, I see that what's taking up space is just the .pkg files. According to discussion elsewhere on apple.SE, those are not needed post-installation, so I removed them, and left anything else that was there.

Comment: @RobertDodier it‘s different for .app‘s, they get installed to /Applications and are only referenced from Caskroom.

Comment: You also could use `brew -prune` with the appropriate parameters to get rid of cached downloads.

Comment: @nohillside `brew prune` is deprecated https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/8096

Answer (score 0):

Removing the files at `/usr/local/Caskroom` [would break upgrade functionality.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/66242)
Yes, it can grow quite a bit.